# Using modifyList() to merge more than two lists

Tags: r, list

I`ve been using`modifyList() ` to combine two lists of similar structure, since other methods usually don't my data structure. However, I now need to apply this process over multiple lists.

```
lst1 <- list("name" = c("paul", "mary", "jane"), "height" = c(188,177,166))
lst2 <- list("color" = c("pink", "grey", "black"), "value" = c(22,33,44))

res <- modifyList(lst1, lst2)
```

gives the desired outcome for two lists

```
> str(res)
List of 4
 $ name  : chr [1:3] "paul" "mary" "jane"
 $ height: num [1:3] 188 177 166
 $ color : chr [1:3] "blue" "red" "green"
 $ value : num [1:3] 12 13 14
```

but how do I apply this over > 2 lists dynamically, i.e.

```
    lst1 <- list("name" = c("paul", "mary", "jane"), "height" = c(188,177,166))
    lst2 <- list("color" = c("pink", "grey", "black"), "value" = c(22,33,44))
    lst3 <- list("type" = c("good", "bad", "ugly"), "weight" = c(80,70,60))
```

The expected output in this case would be:

```
> str(res)
List of 6
 $ name  : chr [1:3] "paul" "mary" "jane"
 $ height: num [1:3] 188 177 166
 $ color : chr [1:3] "blue" "red" "green"
 $ value : num [1:3] 12 13 14
 $ type  : chr [1:3] "good" "bad" "ugly"
 $ weight: num [1:3] 80 70 60
```

Comment: What is your expected output` ?? `Reduce(modifyList, list(lst1, lst2, lst3))`  Your example lists are having completely disjoint list elements.

Comment: thanks. what would the dynamical approach be for a unknown no. of lists?

Comment: It depends on how many list objects are there in the global environment and if it is all having the similar object name, then `Reduce(modifyList, mget(ls(patten = "lst\\d+")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's example, the `list` elements are all disjoint elements which can be joined simply by `c(lst1, lst2, lst3)`.  Using another reproducible example

```
Reduce(modifyList, mget(ls(pattern = "foo\\d+")))
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#$b$c
#[1] "d"

#$b$d
#[1] TRUE


#$e
#[1] 2

#$g
#[1] 4
```

#### data

```
foo1 <-  list(a = 1, b = list(c = "a", d = FALSE))
foo2 <- list(e = 2, b = list(d = TRUE))
foo3 <- list(g = 4, b = list(c = "d"))
```